# how to get a value of id from database table in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

CAKEPHP

I have problem to get id value from table

My table is named `"users"` and have id `PK(int),username(txt) name(txt)`

I have tried

`$this->users->read('users.id)`

To get user id but it doesn't work.

I also tried

`$this->request->session()->read('users.id')`

I wanna to make a condition like

```
if($this->users->read('users.id'))==1
```

because I wanna hide html code from users with other id. 
I also  try use something like that .....`read('users.username')=='admin'`but they wont work too

As you see a try to use session() to get id but dont work to

my login function is

```
public function login()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if ($user) {

                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect(['controller'=>'Accounts']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error('blalalalala');
    }
}
```

This is my first project i cakephp to school so guys can you help me? :)
im weak in php

---

Thx for tips but still dont work.

i use this

```
$id  =  $this->Auth->user('id');  // To get user id 
    $this->set('id', $id);
```

in my AppController in funciton before filter.

and i use for example `if($id==1)` ..... and still dont work. var dump shows null.

i forgot to say but i have `CakePHP 3x version`

Comment: I don't know how you've learned other languages or frameworks, if you tried "trial and error" there as well it must haven been a painful long and hard experience. So I recommend you to start by doing the basic tutorials and then the Auth tutorial of the official documentation: book.cakephp.org It will give you a proper introduction to the framework and solve your auth related question.

Answer (score 1):

To set user any information in controller you can use

```
$this->Auth->user('fieldName');
```

In `AppController` in `beforeFilter` method just set user info which you need, like as below code

```
$id  =  $this->Auth->user('id');  // To get user id 
        $this->set('id', $id);
```

Now in any view you can apply condition like

```
if($id==1) 
--do this--
```

If you want to get user id anywhere you can use, It not allow in cakephp 3.x

```
AuthComponent::user('id')
```

For details you can see [doc](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user)

Comment: It should be noted that the latter method doesn't work in CakePHP 3.x anymore, which the question may be about (there is no `AuthComponent::identify()` with no arguments in CakePHP 2.x).

Comment: Thanks @ndm for your informative comment. I edited my ans.

Answer (score 0):

you can try these:

```
 $this->Auth->user('id'); // for controller action
```

OR

```
$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id'); // for controller and views
```

OR

```
AuthComponent::user('id') // anywhere
```